# slack RTM message

Tags: json, node.js, slack-api, slack

I used node.js to build my slack bot. I used `@slack/client`. its works fine.
now I have a JSON formatted data got through `slack message builder`.
like this,

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "#36a64f",
            "pretext": "Optional text that appears above the attachment block",
            "author_name": "Bobby Tables",
            "author_link": "http://flickr.com/bobby/",
            "author_icon": "http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg",
            "title": "Slack API Documentation",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
            "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Priority",
                    "value": "High",
                    "short": false
                }
            ],
            "image_url": "http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png",
            "footer": "Slack API",
            "footer_icon": "https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png",
            "ts": 123456789
        }
    ]
}
```

if I send this json through the `rtm.sendMessage()` function which displays the json text. how to convert this json to formatted slack message? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
There are two ways to send message to slack:
1)rtm.sendMessage('hello ' + user.name + '!', dm.id); and 
2)you can use api.chatpost message api ,using request module which is used to send data .
i am using this in my project you can also view this , how i do that.
check my github https://github.com/shekhartyagi26/slack_Rtm/
```

Comment: if you have any query tor issue you can ask me